# Writing multiple lines in a file in C

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, command-prompt

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
  FILE * fp;
  int i,n;
  char str[20];
  printf("Enter the number of lines to be written: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  fp = fopen ("abc.txt","w"); 
  for(i = 0; i < n+1;i++)
  {
    gets(str);
    fputs(str, fp);
  }

  fclose (fp);
  return 0;
}
```

In this code, I am able to write multiple lines but when I check the result in the notepad, these multiple lines are displayed in a single line. How can I make them appear as I typed in the command prompt (here I am using Visual Studio 2008 command prompt).

Comment: looks like u missed a `newline` character.

Comment: Is there a reason you're *not* using [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) for this? It would assist in killing both your current problem and the buffer overflow vulnerability of your current code. `gets()` is evil, so much so it has been officially thrown out of the standard library.

Answer (score 2):

You replace existing so add

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main ()
    {
      FILE * fp;
      int i,n;
      char str[20];
      printf("Enter the number of lines to be written: ");
      scanf("%d", &n);
      fp = fopen ("abc.txt","w"); 
      for(i = 0; i < n+1;i++)
      {
        gets(str);
        fputs(str, fp);
        fputs("\n", fp);
      }

      fclose (fp);
      return 0;
    }
```

after add your input.

```
    fputs("\n", fp);
```

add new line to your file abc.txt after your text get added.

Answer (score 1):

Add something like this,

```
fputs(str, fp);
fputs("\r\n", fp); /* add a Windows new line */
```

Comment: Better to `fputs("\n", fp);` which will, on Windows systems, translate into `"\r\n"` by the OS as the file was opened in _text_ mode.  It is more portable too.

Answer (score 1):

You may try like this:

```
fputs("\n", fp);
```

ie, put a `\n` to move to the next line. `\n` is used as a newline character in C

Comment: why not carriage return `fputc('\r', fp);`  ?

Comment: @chouaib Code needs to append the end-of-line, which is `'\n'` in C.  As the file is opened in _text_ mode, the I/O functions will translate the `'\n'` into `"\n"`, or `"\r"`, or `"\r\n"` or whatever is needed for text files on the target system.  Writing `'\r'` simple writes `'\r'` which aside from being a white-space has not special meaning in C.

Answer (score 0):

You need to append \r\n to each line. (Carriage return plus line feed.)

UNIX requires just \n but some of the Windows tools don't deal with that well.

Comment: Only if the file is opened in binary mode, which it's not.

Comment: The file is already in text-mode. The standard library is *supposed* to properly translate new line as needed for the target platform to maintain portability. If it were opened in "wb" that onus would be on the developer.

Answer (score 0):

As WhozCraig pointed out, gets is evil and is akin to asking for a buffer overflow.

But to answer your question, add a CRLF (carriage return + line feed) like such:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){ 
    FILE* fp;
    int n;
    char str[20];
    printf("Enter the number of lines to be written: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    fp = fopen ("abc.txt","w"); 
    for(int i = 0; i < n+1;i++){
        gets(str);
        fputs(str, fp);
        fputs("\r\n", fp);
    }
    fclose (fp);
    return 0;
}
```